# Can PHP ping a remote system without ICMP and without external programs?

Tags: php, ping

I want to check if another machine is generally responding with PHP.

Most approaches are to ping some service running on the target machine, but I want to check if the machine is online generally.

I've found http://birk-jensen.dk/2010/09/php-ping/ which supposedly sends an ICMP Ping package. The problem is, somehow one is required to be `root` to perform a `socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, 1)`. The workaround via `posix_seteuid(0)` doesn't work either, since elevated permissions are required for that too.

Any functions that would let me run the `ping`  program are not available in my scenario either.

So how do I check if a server is online using php?

Comment: `system('ping yahoo.com')` ??

Comment: Do you have access to the remote server (e.g. ssh)?

Comment: If you do not have permissions do create an ICMP socket, and you do not have permissions to execute an external program to run ICMP echo, then you cannot perform an ICMP echo. If you also don't want to based your check on some service or other that you would have permissions to connect to, then you're kind of stuck. It is unlikely that you would need to be specifically `root` for this, your user account would simply need to be given this permission. Contact the server administrator and see if they can do this for you.

Comment: @CarlOwens SSH is a good idea, since it's stable and *should* always be running. I'll use that until there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast What is the exact use case here? Is the target machine "any arbitrary IP address" or a specific set of machines?

Comment: Open any port of other server. Most time 80, 22 will work. If openning socket succeeds, server is up.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Will that work even when there is no underlying service to respond? I don't think so...

Comment: @DaveRandom the use case is to build a status monitor from an external webspace (external because it's a bit schizophrenic to let the machines in doubt monitor themselves...)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast No if there is not service running. Then machine is not online. But you have to check all the ports.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Yeah right, I could check all ports from 0 to 65536 and if one responds the server is online! Might wanna write that as an ajax thing since it could take some time...

Comment: @Cobra_Fast you want to check `another machine is generally responding with PHP`. and that machine has 65535 ports. Nmap checks it within 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Nice that some C/C++ program can do it that fast, but I just tested it and php spends roughly 3 minutes on checking all these ports (in case the server is offline).

Comment: @Cobra_Fast It is possible to do it a-synchronously in PHP, set the sockets to non-blocking mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Net_Ping to ping from php
http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Ping/redirected

Answer (score 1):

for this you might want to try, this is highly unlikely to give meaningful data, but is something to grok over.

if you open a tcp socket to a random port and instead of timing out it closes immediately. then the machine is "up", however this does not mean much more then that. it could be in a kernel panic.

and a timeout does not mean that the machine is down. just that instead of rejecting the tcp handshake it dropped it.

you wont be able to get any kind of meaningful timing data with this, but will give more of an educated guess if the machine in question is on or off.

```
<?php
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_connect ( $sock , string $address,22 ) === true) {
switch(socket_last_error($sock)) {
    case 110:
    case 112:
    case 113:
       echo 'Machine may be down';
       break;
    case 111:
       echo 'Machine may be up';
       break;
    case 115:
       echo 'Machine is up';
       break;
    default:
       echo 'Machine in unknown state.';
       break;
}
```

you already stated that you can't use the ping command so Net_Ping will not work as it is just a fancy interface to the ping command in the operating system